# regular expression to delete separator and text after separator

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I am looking for a regular expression which removes text after a separator and removes the separator as well.
I tried `.*&` to remove text after `&`. This is working but I want to remove `&` from my string as well.

Like `&`, I  have multiple other separators e.g `, ; \ / - | (JT)`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a bit vague - could you post more examples of input strings and the desired output? E.g., should the regex remove everything after the very first separator is found? Per line or for the entire string? Should it treat all separators equally?

Comment: Example : FirstName & LastName
Expected output  = FirstName

Comment: What about all the other separators? What kind of a separator is `(JT)`? Please edit your post and add several examples. Use Ctrl-K to indent them 4 spaces so they will be formatted as "raw text".

Comment: Example : FirstName (JT) LastName

Answer (score 0):

With `.*&` you're matching the text until and including the *last* `&` in your text. If you don't want to include that in the match, put it in a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
.*(?=&)
```

To look for more than one separator, use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
.*(?=[&,;\\/|-]|\(JT\))
```

Note that this will change something like

```
First, Middle & Last
```

to

```
First, Middle
```

because the match stops before the *last* separator. If you want it to stop at the *first* separator, use a lazy [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
.*?(?=[&,;\\/|-]|\(JT\))
```

Note that you will need to escape the backslashes for the string processor, so that regex, written as a string, will look like

```
".*?(?=[&,;\\\\/|-]|\\(JT\\))"
```

Comment: Thank you for reply . I tried regular expressions you have provided. Input I provided was FirstName (JT) LastName and output I got is **FirstName ,**  where are expected output is "FirstName" .

Comment: Do you mean that the space after FirstName should be removed? Then you shouldn't use `"(JT)"` as a separator but `" (JT) "`. Just add spaces to the regex where you want them to be matched.

Comment: I am ok with  space after 1st name but comma should not be appended.

Comment: You must be adding the comma yourself - there is no comma in the text you quoted, and the regex itself can't add new text. You probably have a comma in the replacement text you're using. Since you didn't show how you're using the regex, I can't say more.